# How to simplify this equation to a specific form?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I simplify this expression?

$$ 2(4^{n-1})-(-3)^{n-1} + 12 ( 2 (4^{n-2})-(-3)^{n-2})$$

The correct answer is $2 · 4^n − (−3)^n$

Answer (score 1):

First, note that simplification is not really a well-defined mathematical operation -- we simplify things to communicate our equations more clearly, but the notion of "simplest" form of an expression is far from standardized (unless your teacher has given you specific rules).

That said, we can see how to convert your expression into the form you want, $a4^n + b(-3)^n$. First, I'd start by changing all term with powers into ones with only $n$ in the exponent:
$$2\left(\frac{4^n}{4}\right)-\frac{(-3)^n}{-3}+12\left(2\left(\frac{4^n}{16}\right) - \frac{(-3)^n}{9}\right).$$

Now we can group together terms involving $4^n$ and $(-3)^n$:
$$\left(\frac{2}{4}+\frac{24}{16}\right)4^n + \left(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{12}{9}\right)(-3)^n.$$

Now we just simplify the stuff in parentheses:
$$2\cdot 4^n - (-3)^n.$$

Answer (score 0):

**hint:**

use the fact that
$$a^n = a\cdot a^{n-1}$$
and that
$$a^n = a^2\cdot a^{n-2}$$